# how to replace file extension

Tags: bash, shell-script

we want to replace the script file extension

so we did the following:

```
 new_name=` echo run_fix.bash  |  sed 's/[.].*$//' `
 new_file_extension=".in_hold.txt"
 new_name=$new_name$new_file_extension

 echo $new_name
 run_fix.in_hold.txt
```

but I feel my approach is not so elegant

note - because script extension could be bash or perl or python and also the target extension could be any thing after "." we want global replacement

---

I am using redhat 7.2

Comment: Don't give scripts file-name-extensions: The caller should not need to know what language a script is written in. Instead, use `#!…`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
old_name=run_fix.bash
new_name=${old_name%.bash}.in_hold.txt

printf 'New name: %s\n' "$new_name"
```

This would remove the filename suffix `.bash` from the value of `$old_name` and add `.in_hold.txt` to the result of that.  The whole thing would be assigned to the variable `new_name`.

The expansion `${variable%pattern}` to remove the shortest suffix string matching the pattern `pattern` from the value of `$variable` is [a standard parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

To replace *any* filename suffix (i.e. anything after the last dot in the filename):

```
new_name=${old_name%.*}.new_suffix
```

The `.*` pattern would match the last dot and anything after it (this would be removed).  Had you used `%%` instead of `%`, the *longest* substring that matched the pattern would have been removed (in this case, you would have removed everything after the *first* dot in the string).   If the string does not contain any dots, it remains unaltered.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because although I knew how to do this, I did not understand what was happening. You explain this clearly and concisely, with a link to further details. A model answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `rename` command, by larry wall. Not installed by default on all systems, and some have a different command with this name. It is definitely available for Debian based systems.

`rename` is `sed` for filenames.

Comment: It's more like Perl for filenames as as far as I can tell, you could put a whole perl program into a rename operation, given that you use the Perl implementation of `rename`.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes it is very flexible, but you can also just use it like `sed` (but for file-names). No need to scare people.